# add field on vendor screen

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

when I add a new field, in the payment configuration tab.

It adds the field in location to the database, but at the same time I create DAC addressExt, I don't understand why.

here is the DAC of each one that created me.

First.

the field is created in this table: Location

namespace PX.Objects.CR.Standalone
{

```
public class LocationExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.Location>
{
    #region UsrTest
    [PXDBBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="test")]
    public virtual bool? UsrTest { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrTest : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<usrTest> { }
    #endregion
}
```

}

second.

namespace PX.Objects.CR
{

```
public class AddressExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CR.Address>
{
    #region UsrTest
    [PXDBBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "test")]
    public virtual bool? UsrTest { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrTest : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<usrTest> { }
    #endregion
}
```

}

view image:

I hope you understand, I'm not good at English.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you make it clearer or try asking it a different way?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually being done by design.  The DAC you are editing is a Projection consisting of multiple DACs.  Check this [link](https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2018/07/custom-field-on-cr-quote-screen.html) out from Sergey Marenich

> PXProjection uses 2 Data Access Classes for quotes:

> One class represents the table – PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.CRQuote.
> Another represents view as combination of DACs in select – PX.Objects.CR.CRQuote.
> And to correctly work, custom field needs to be added in both of the places. And Projection field should be linked to table field using BqlField property of DBFieldAttributes.